# set value in third nested array of objects mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I have below structure of mongodb document:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fca578a983edc31764f80d2"
  },
  "class_name": "Class 1",
  "meeting": [
    {
      "id": "1641278777739",
      "teacher_id": "5fca5769c4e2e859c71c7de2",
      "teacher_name": "Mrs. Miller",
      "dates": [
        {
          "id": 1641377951854,
          "meeting": "2022-01-7 1:08:00",
          "student_id": null,
          "student": null
        },
        {
          "id": 1641377970597,
          "meeting": "2022-01-26 11:19:00",
          "student_id": null,
          "student": null
        }
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

I have id of object which is in meeting array and id of dates object which is inside meeting.
I want to set the value of student_id inside **dates**, I'm using mongodb and mongodb php client. How I can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you always have the same structure of this array? Also are do you want to set the same student_id for each dates?

Comment: @AngelDeykov in meeting array there are multiple objects which can vary and each meeting object has dates array of objects, in dates array there can be multiple objects as well which can vary. I have id of meeting object and date object where I want to set the value of student_id.

Comment: and student id is same  for each meetings and dates ?

Comment: I have to set the value in student_id inside dates, its doesn't matter if its same or not for all. probably it will be different.

Answer (score 0):

mongo shell JS version:

```
 db.collection.update({},
 {
  $set: {
    "meeting.$[m].dates.$[k].student_id": "value"
  }
 },
{
   arrayFilters: [
     {
       "m.id": "1641278777739"
    },
    {
       "k.id": 1641377970597
    }
  ]
})
```

explained:
You use two arrayFilters to select the exact nesteed object where you will update in your case the student_id key with the new value ...
[javascript playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UePq6csKYzQ)

php version:

```
  $db->collection->update([],
 [
   '$set'=>["meeting.$[m].dates.$[k].student_id" => "value" ]
 ],
 [
   'arrayFilters'=>  [
                       "m.id"=> "1641278777739" , 
                       "k.id"=>1641377970597
                     ]
 ]
);
```